# .htaccess: Multiple TLD's to 1 TLD excluding subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I have multiple TLD's (domainX.com, domainY.net, ...) pointing towards the same folder. In this folder I would like to add a .htaccess file to redirect ALL www and non-www URL's that aren't domainY.com to domainY.com.

There is one twist here however. I have some subdomains: alfa.domainY.com and beta.domainY.com and gamma.domainY.com set-up, which in all my tests keep redirecting to domainY.com.

Any chance anyone can give me a successful bit of code here?

EDIT: Maybe also add some `#Comments`, I noticed most answers here lack that, and I think it means some of them can't be reused as people don't know what they do. I can also add this myself afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file of your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !domainY\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainY.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The expression matching the host will fail for any **alpha.domainY.net** because it only matches against the TLD (.net) and domain (domainY).

The first line turns on the rewrite engine.

The second line, the condition, is a true/false expression that is applied to the immediately following rule. In this case, it checks the request's `Host:` header, and if it **ends with** `domainY.net`, then the condition fails, because of the `!` in front.

The third line is the rule, the URI is used to match against the pattern `^(.*)$` which essentially matches everything, and is captured via the parentheses. Then the next bit is the target. If the rule matches, which it does because the pattern matches everything, then the target is applied, and in this case, it redirects the browser to `domainY.net` and passes the same URI along with it via the regex backreference `$1`.

Comment: Thanks Jon! That works perfectly. I must admit not completely understanding the code. Would you mind adding some comments inline to explain it. That way it's a great resource for future use too!